# How to import from packages init.py

Tags: python

I'm reading http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html.

I got a package with this structure:

```
package/
__init__.py
    file.py
    file2.py
    file3.py
    subpackage/
        __init__.py
        submodule1.py
        submodule2.py
```

Lets say I have variable `db` declared in package/__init__.py and I want to import db into file.py, would I do it as:

file1.py:

```
from package import db
```

?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do `from package import db` if your package is on your PYTHONPATH, or you can do `from . import db` otherwise. (that's a relative import).

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to be sure!